IEnumerable.Select() inside DbSet<>.Include() instead of DbSet<>.IncludeThen() in EF Core 8
I'm trying to define abstract repository, children of which will pass to GetById() method list of Func<T, object> to manage includes of different level. So, I need to pass second-level property of T to include this instead manual use of .IncludeThen() method.
After some research I found solution for EF 6 like to pass x.Users.Select(u => u.Posts), but for EF Core 8 it is not working and throwing this exception:

The expression 'x.Users.AsQueryable().Select(u => u.Posts)' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'`

Also I thought about getting Users.Posts string for passing into Include() from func x => x.Users.Select(u => u.Posts), but did not get it.
Generic method of abstract generic repository:
protected T? GetById(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    => Entities
        .IncludeAll(includes)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

Extension method IncludeAll():
public static IQueryable<T> IncludeAll<T>(this IQueryable<T> entities, Expression<Func<T, object>>[]? includes)
    where T : Entity, new()
{
    if (includes is null)
    {
        return entities;
    }

    entities = includes.Aggregate(entities,
        (current, include) => current.Include(include));

    return entities;
}

Concrete repository method:
public override Topic? GetById(int id)
{
    return base.GetById(id, x => x.Users.Select(u => u.Posts));
}

Please, help me understand why my code stops with such exception and how can I provide access to List inside List property for Include() method.
Or how can I modify my extension method IncludeAll() to get "Users.Posts" string for passing into Include() from func x => x.Users.Select(u => u.Posts).
PS: Topic entity contains List<User> Users property in this example. User entity has List<Post> Posts property.
I have tried to find some same problems, but did not found them.

Make protected IQueryable<T> GetById(int id) => Entities.Where(x => x.Id == id) and let the children call it as base.GetById(id).Include(...).FirstOrDefault().

"Also I thought about getting "Users.Posts" string for passing into Include()" - alternatively you can just accept a collection of include strings for the includes parameter rather than expressions.
